# Easiest way to burn a blu-ray data disks in Linux

Tags: linux, blu-ray

Does anyone know whats the easiest way to burn tar files onto a blu-ray disk?

Also will it be possible to burn more than 25 GB of disk space, which would spanned to more than one blu-ray disk? For example like a 40GB tar archive, using two 25GB disks.

I've tried using the growiso utility directly and it doesn't appear that this option is supported. I've looked into k3b but from what I understand, k3b uses growisofs underneath the hood.

```
    [root@livecd windows]# growisofs --dry-run -Z /dev/sr0 -volset-size=2 -iso-level 4   allow-lowercase -l -J backup_20120119_1332/

    Executing 'mkisofs -volset-size=2 -iso-level 4 -allow-lowercase -l -J backup_20120119_1332/ | builtin_dd of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
    mkisofs: Volume Set Size > 1 not yet supported`
```

Comment: For a 40GB tar archive, split it before burning with the `split` command.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, this was actually exactly what I was looking for.